# How to Create an Encrypted Password

Tags: password, encryption, passwd

I want to know how can I create an encrypted password in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Tried this:

```
makepasswd --crypt-md5 password_here
```

It did not work for me. It is throwing this Error:

```
sysadmin@localhost:~$ makepasswd --crypt-md5 admin123

makepasswd:  Non-argument options specified:  admin123
makepasswd:  For more information, type:  makepasswd --help
```

I want to add those encrypted password in one of the installation so I need the way of doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# echo -n admin123 | makepasswd --crypt-md5 --clearfrom -
admin123     $1$ZUNNSLzQ$XsViFC1bhucsr3f8AzMPt/
```

As commented bellow this command is unsecure. True method - write password in file with text editor, and read password from file.

Comment: Excuse me: add -n to echo.

Comment: Note that the reason `makepasswd` doesn't read the password as an argument is that arguments are visible to anyone with access to the server, simply by running `ps`. Thus by putting it as an argument to `echo`, you're making it visible.

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved if you explained why OP's command didn't work and yours did, instead of just throwing a valid solution without an explanation. Also, @Patrick has a point, to which I would add command history.

Comment: @Patrick Passing a password as an argument to `makepasswd` would expose it to other users via `ps`, but not passing it to `echo`. `echo` is a builtin in all contemporary shells. Command history, on the other hand, is a good reason not to do it this way — alternatively, you can disable command history for the duration.

Comment: Was wondering when someone was going to call me out on that. Yes, in almost all cases it is. But it's not a habit I would encourage as it's not guaranteed.

Comment: I would avoid providing password anywhere in the command. Instead, you can enter a password. Like this: `read -p "Enter password :" -s PASSWORD; echo; echo $PASSWORD | makepasswd --crypt-md5 --clearfrom -`

Answer (score 8):

Another way is this: `openssl passwd -1 -stdin <<< password_here`

This does not show the password on the process list. For more options see `openssl passwd --help`

Comment: It does not show password on the process list, but it can still be seen in history. I would propose something like this `read -p "Enter password: " -s PASSWORD; echo; openssl passwd -1 -stdin <<< $PASSWORD`.

Answer (score 3):

Your method doesn't work because `makepasswd` doesn't accept a password as argument, you should create a temporary clear text file instead to make the password if you want to generate the hash based on a password:

```
➜  ~  makepasswd --crypt-md5 --clearfrom file
admin123   $1$iQd/ujH.$rMXZiYwQC1Rc/rgO3.FeX/
```

Of course, do not use the command line to store the password as it will be accessible by anyone that can read your command history or process arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Just run:

```bsh
openssl passwd -6 -stdin
```

and then type/paste your password, then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> ("end of file"). No password will be seen in process list and no password will be saved into shell history.

See more password algorithms with:

```bsh
 % openssl passwd -help    
Usage: passwd [options]
Valid options are:
 -help               Display this summary
 -in infile          Read passwords from file
 -noverify           Never verify when reading password from terminal
 -quiet              No warnings
 -table              Format output as table
 -reverse            Switch table columns
 -salt val           Use provided salt
 -stdin              Read passwords from stdin
 -6                  SHA512-based password algorithm
 -5                  SHA256-based password algorithm
 -apr1               MD5-based password algorithm, Apache variant
 -1                  MD5-based password algorithm
 -aixmd5             AIX MD5-based password algorithm
 -crypt              Standard Unix password algorithm (default)
 -rand val           Load the file(s) into the random number generator
 -writerand outfile  Write random data to the specified file
```

Answer (score -1):

You can instead use AES(Advanced Enryption Standard) Algorithm, which is open source and comparatively much secured to encrypt your password.

references: https://www.aescrypt.com/

Comment: Even if the names are similar, crypt does not encrypt passwords as aescrypt encrypt files. Aescrypt cannot be used to transform passwords to be used in ubuntu.