# Generating more secure password with random-generated salt periodically?

Tags: shell-script, security, password, password-store

Is there way to make passwords even more secure for ie.using schecluded Bash Script to change randomly-generated salt for the users' passwords for ie. two times per month without regular and ordinary server user doesn't know nothing about it or it has no effect on user behaviour or that he doesn't have to make any action with his password himself?

Reference-link for earlier forum topic where moderator told me to ask new question after my comment was deleted is located on
[How to Create an Encrypted Password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134827/how-to-create-an-encrypted-password/579248#579248)

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Unix & Linux StackExchange!

The problem with that idea is that the password hashes are **not reversible**: instead of "decrypting" the hashed password and comparing that to user input at login time, the password the user is inputting is hashed with the same salt as the stored password hash, and then the result is compared to the stored hash. If they match, it is assumed that the user entered a valid password and the login is accepted.

(Yes, it is theoretically possible that two password inputs might result in the same hash, but that is *extremely* unlikely.)

In order to be able to re-hash all the passwords with a new salt without involving the users, you would have to store a plaintext (or reversibly-encrypted and thus plaintext-equivalent) version of everyone's current passwords. That's precisely the thing the password hashing scheme was designed to avoid in the first place.

Re-hashing an existing password with a new salt is not even very useful: if an evil person had managed to get a copy of your password hashes before re-hashing, they could bruteforce the hashes with the old salt at their leisure, and then use any discovered passwords with your system with the new salts, *because the actual passwords the system requests at login time are still the same.*

The purpose of using salted hashes in password storage is two-fold:

1.) it prevents the administrators viewing the hashes from casually noticing that two users have the same actual password,

2.) if the file with the password hashes gets into malicious hands, it gives the system administrators time to notice the leak and get the users to change their passwords before malicious logins can happen. (Good passwords might actually be resistant to dictionary attacks, but guaranteeing that requires implementing password quality checks at the time the passwords are set or changed.)

Note that in modern systems, the password hashes are stored in `/etc/shadow` which is not readable by regular users. So if the hashes get into malicious hands, it means the security of your system is already pretty severely compromised - and you have bigger problems than worrying about your users' grumbling about the need to change passwords!

Comment: Thanks for good answer! That helped me a lot! Finnish Ubuntu discusiion community moderator answered me similiar question that you can't salt user -password if you don't know it yourself. Plain-text -format is out of principles of all security basics? But how about if I overwrite reversed passwd, and chpasswd aliases or one of them and make symbolic link to other that when my server user changes his/her password in terminal with passwd magic with switches and couple of parameters will be happen under the hood? (SHA512 crypting, Random Salt-String added, and great amount of SHA Rounds)?

Comment: I'm doing that for my own Administrator and superuser passwords myself. I think it's best practice to make password -cracking even harded for homegrown red - hat cracker or any kind of script-kid with their home computers.

Comment: If you want to change how the `passwd` or `chpasswd` command works, the best place to do it in the files in `/etc/pam.d/`. Unless you're using an obsolete Linux distribution, SHA512 with a random salt is *already* the default. All the standard tools will use the PAM libraries to handle the authentication, so you should look at the options to `pam_unix.so` (see `man pam_unix` or `man pam_unix.so`) or if you want to, program your own PAM authentication library that does exactly what you want. But the standard system is pretty well-thought-out: you might do more harm than good by changing it.